# Editing the Minitoc to include the word Page above the page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I have browsed through the manual for the minitoc and I haven't been able to find whether there is a way to do the following:

For the TOC it is possible to add the word `Page` above the page number column using:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
```

Is there a way to do the same for a minitoc at the beginning of `\chapter` that doesn't end up writing something also in the general TOC?

Please find an MWE below

```
\documentclass[
DIV=11,
twoside,
headinclude=false,
titlepage=firstiscover,
abstract=true,
headsepline=true,
footsepline=true,
chapterprefix=true, %this allows for editing of the chapter titles
headings=big,
bibliography=totoc,%adds unnumbered Bibliography chapter to toc
captions=tableheading
]{scrreprt}

%%% Packages
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\linespread{1.5} %imperial uses 1.5 
\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%% ToC DEPTH LEVEL
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % number subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % list subsubsection
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{4}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Entry of TOC LOF LOT
\def\body{
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \cleardoublepage
\linespread{1.25}
    %%% MINITOC
    \dominitoc
    % MINITOC styling
    \renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\normalsize\fontfamily{jkpss}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\normalsize\bf\fontfamily{jkpss}\selectfont}

    %%% TOC
    \tableofcontents
    \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %Adds the word Page
    \cleardoublepage

    %%% LOF
    \listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
    \addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %Adds the word Page
    \cleardoublepage

    %%% LOT
    \listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables} 
    \addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %Adds the word Page
    \cleardoublepage


    \pagestyle{headings}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}

\begin{document}

\body

\chapter{First Chapter}
\linespread{1}
\dictum[Neil deGrasse Tyson]{The good thing about science is that it's true whether or not you believe in it.}

\minitoc

Here is some introduction

\section{Here is a section for the minitoc}
Bla bla.

\subsection{And why not a subsection too}
Just to spice things up a bit.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a more or less minimal example of a document including the minitoc on chapter level.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to add it earlier.

Comment: If you want it above something else, why not make a `tabular`?

Comment: @666 It is an option but having it look a part of the minitoc would be preferred personally. The first answer by Keks already sets off on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to your preamble:

```
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{Contents \hspace{13.5cm} Page}
```

Unfortunately `\hfill` renders an incorrect result.

---

**EDIT**

`\hspace{}` inside `\mtcsettitle`is not a good idea, many errors, no clue, why. Ahem, an even more dirty version:

```
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{Contents \textcolor{white}{mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm} Page}
```

Of course you could swap the m's against some text of yours, only visible to people who try to copy out of your PDF.

Comment: Is there any reason why this is flashing up so many errors?

Comment: By the way thank you, the style is exactly what I was looking for I would simply like to know if the errors can be removed / can be ignored as they won't affect other things

Comment: Probably the solution with `\hfill` just needs some juggling with `\expandafter` or `\protect`. But I edited my answer and now it compiles without errors. I know, it is _very_ hackish and dirty, hopefully somebody can improve it.

Comment: Well for now it's a solution that works as no other method of filling the space seems to go down well. Sometimes the dirty approach is the right one :). I will accept your reply for the time being as there isn't much wrong with it. Thank you.